# Adding "redirect" to a button

Tags: php

So, I have the following code:

```
    <?php if ( I_delete_user($user_id) || $demo_site->request_verification($user_id) || isset( $args["{$template}_button_primary"] ) || isset( $args["{$template}_button_secondary"] ) ) { ?>
        <div class="submit_it">             
            <?php if (isset($args["{$template}_button_primary"]) ) { ?>
                <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $args["{$template}_button_primary"]; ?>" class="my-button" />
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Users can upload their picture and save it by clicking "submit" button while staying in the page.

I am trying to add a function so that when an user clicks this "submit" button on a specific page (post_id of 222, for example), the user is redirected to a different page (demo.com/another_page) once the save is done.

I am not sure how to go about it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a hook (such as [`init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) or [`admin_init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init)) to detect whether a condition has been met. For instance, the existence of a certain querystring variable (which can be a url encoded url, if you like).

When the condition is met, use [`wp_safe_redirect()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect) (and optionally [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)) to redirect to the URL you want. You can either hard-code that URL or fetch it from the querystring if your button passed it along as a urlencoded variable.

Hypothetical example (PHP 5.3+ syntax):

```
add_action('init', function(){
    if ( isset($_REQUEST['redirect_to']) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect($_REQUEST['redirect_to']);
        exit();
    }
});
```